# OPENSHIFT RHC SSH connection refused

Tags: ssh, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I have 2 apps (old-app & new-app), I **am able** to connect to the newer app via `RHC SSH new-app`... but now I'm not able to SSH into my old-app.  I get `port 22: Connection refused`.

I tried deleting my express.conf and re-running RHC setup... but still no change.  I can SSH into the newer app (so it's not a firewall/port 22 issue), but I'm not able to SSH into the old app that used to work fine (via RHC SSH).

Anyone else experience this?  Anything else I can try?

BTW, I'm on UBUNTU.

Comment: Are the apps on the same account?

Comment: I've also tried deleting the .ssh files and re-running RHC setup again. Still getting the same connection refused error on the old-app but not on the new-app.